# How change shape and size of custom drawn shader in glsurface view by getting coordinates from view class

Tags: java, android, view, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

In my application i'm having a custom graph like view firstly beneath the overlaying graph view there is a custom cameraview which extends glsurfaceview here inside camera view class i'm applying live blur filter to camera of device without any problems but however i want to change the shape and size of blur as per the coordinate of my overlay grap view here i'm attaching screenshots of my application:

Below Is the screenshot of what i'm trying to achieve:

[image: Screenshot of what i want to achieve]

Below Is Screenshot of What i'm actaully getting:

[image: Screenshot of what i'm getting]

Here's my overlaying view class:

```
public class OverlayView2 extends View {


    MainActivity f2396a;


    double f2397b;


    double f2398c;


    double f2399d;

    double f2400e;


    double f2401f;


    int f2402g = 1;


    C0905a[] f2403h = {new C0905a(), new C0905a(), new C0905a(), new C0905a(), new C0905a()};


    Paint f2404i = new Paint();


    double f2405j = 1.0d;


    double f2406k;


    double f2407l;


    double f2408m;

    class C0905a {


        double f2409a;


        double f2410b;


        int f2411c = -1;


        double f2412d;


        double f2413e;

        C0905a() {
        }
    }

    public OverlayView2(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        mo3504a();
        if (!isInEditMode() && (context instanceof MainActivity)) {
            this.f2396a = (MainActivity) context;
        }
    }

    public static float m4357a(Context context, float f) {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(1, f, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    public void mo3504a() {
        this.f2397b = 0.0d;
        this.f2398c = 0.0d;
        this.f2399d = 0.0d;
        this.f2400e = 0.4d;
        this.f2401f = 0.25d;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void mo3505a(double d, double d2, double d3, double d4, Canvas canvas) {
        double width = (double) ((getWidth() + getHeight()) * 2);
        canvas.drawLine((float) (d - (d3 * width)), (float) (d2 - (d4 * width)), (float) ((d3 * width) + d), (float) ((width * d4) + d2), this.f2404i);
    }

    public void mo3506a(double d, double d2, Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(new RectF((float) (0.0d - d), (float) (0.0d - d2), (float) (0.0d + d), (float) (0.0d + d2)), this.f2404i);
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: 0000 */
    /* renamed from: b */
    public void mo3507b() {
        double scale = getScale();
        double width = (((double) getWidth()) * 0.5d) + (this.f2397b * scale);
        double height = (((double) getHeight()) * 0.5d) + (this.f2398c * scale);
        double cos = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.f2399d)) * this.f2400e * scale;
        double sin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.f2399d)) * this.f2400e * scale;
        double d = (-Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.f2399d))) * this.f2401f * scale;
        double cos2 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.f2399d)) * this.f2401f * scale;
        this.f2403h[0].f2409a = width;
        this.f2403h[0].f2410b = height;
        this.f2403h[1].f2409a = width - cos;
        this.f2403h[1].f2410b = height - sin;
        this.f2403h[2].f2409a = cos + width;
        this.f2403h[2].f2410b = sin + height;
        this.f2403h[3].f2409a = width - d;
        this.f2403h[3].f2410b = height - cos2;
        this.f2403h[4].f2409a = width + d;
        this.f2403h[4].f2410b = height + cos2;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale((float) (this.f2400e * scale), (float) (this.f2401f * scale));
        matrix.postRotate((float) this.f2399d);
        matrix.postTranslate(((float) getWidth()) * 0.5f, ((float) getHeight()) * 0.5f);
        matrix.postTranslate((float) (this.f2397b * scale), (float) (scale * this.f2398c));
        matrix.postScale(1.0f / ((float) getWidth()), -1.0f / ((float) getHeight()));
        matrix.postTranslate(0.0f, 1.0f);
        matrix.invert(matrix);
       if (this.f2396a != null && this.f2396a.cameraView != null) {
           /* matrix.getValues(this.f2396a.cameraView.f2132f);*/
        }
    }

    public void mo3508c() {
        double d;
        double scale = getScale();
        C0905a aVar = this.f2403h[0];
        if (aVar.f2411c >= 0) {
            this.f2397b = (aVar.f2409a - (((double) getWidth()) * 0.5d)) / scale;
            this.f2398c = (aVar.f2410b - (((double) getHeight()) * 0.5d)) / scale;
        }
        double d2 = 0.0d;
        int i = 0;
        double d3 = 0.0d;
        double d4 = 0.0d;
        int i2 = 0;
        int i3 = 0;
        for (int i4 = 1; i4 < this.f2403h.length; i4++) {
            C0905a aVar2 = this.f2403h[i4];
            if (aVar2.f2411c >= 0) {
                if (i4 == 1) {
                    d2 += Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(-(aVar2.f2410b - this.f2403h[0].f2410b), -(aVar2.f2409a - this.f2403h[0].f2409a)));
                    i++;
                }
                if (i4 == 2) {
                    d2 += Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(aVar2.f2410b - this.f2403h[0].f2410b, aVar2.f2409a - this.f2403h[0].f2409a));
                    i++;
                }
                if (this.f2402g != 1) {
                    if (i4 == 3) {
                        d2 += Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(aVar2.f2409a - this.f2403h[0].f2409a, -(aVar2.f2410b - this.f2403h[0].f2410b)));
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (i4 == 4) {
                        d2 += Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(-(aVar2.f2409a - this.f2403h[0].f2409a), aVar2.f2410b - this.f2403h[0].f2410b));
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                double d5 = (this.f2403h[0].f2409a - aVar2.f2409a) / scale;
                double d6 = (this.f2403h[0].f2410b - aVar2.f2410b) / scale;
                if (i4 == 1 || i4 == 2) {
                    double cos = (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.f2399d)) * d5) + (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.f2399d)) * d6);
                    if (i4 == 2) {
                        cos = -cos;
                    }
                    d = Math.max(0.0d, cos) + d3;
                    i2++;
                } else {
                    d = d3;
                }
                if (i4 == 3 || i4 == 4) {
                    double cos2 = ((-Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.f2399d))) * d5) + (d6 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.f2399d)));
                    if (i4 == 4) {
                        cos2 = -cos2;
                    }
                    d4 += Math.max(0.0d, cos2);
                    i3++;
                    d3 = d;
                } else {
                    d3 = d;
                }
            }
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            this.f2399d = d2 / ((double) i);
        }
        if (i2 > 0) {
            this.f2400e = d3 / ((double) i2);
        }
        if (i3 > 0) {
            this.f2401f = d4 / ((double) i3);
        }
        if (this.f2397b < -0.8d) {
            this.f2397b = -0.8d;
        }
        if (this.f2398c < -0.8d) {
            this.f2398c = -0.8d;
        }
        if (this.f2397b > 0.8d) {
            this.f2397b = 0.8d;
        }
        if (this.f2398c > 0.8d) {
            this.f2398c = 0.8d;
        }
        if (this.f2400e < 0.05d) {
            this.f2400e = 0.05d;
        }
        if (this.f2401f < 0.05d) {
            this.f2401f = 0.05d;
        }
        if (this.f2400e > 1.0d) {
            this.f2400e = 1.0d;
        }
        if (this.f2401f > 1.0d) {
            this.f2401f = 1.0d;
        }
    }


    public double getHandleRadius() {
        return (double) m4357a(getContext(), 16.0f);
    }

    public double getScale() {
        return (double) (((float) (getWidth() + getHeight())) * 0.5f);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (this.f2402g != 0) {
            this.f2404i.setColor(-1140850689);
            this.f2404i.setStrokeWidth(m4357a(getContext(), 1.5f));
            this.f2404i.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            this.f2404i.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.save();
            double scale = getScale();
            canvas.translate(((float) getWidth()) * 0.5f, ((float) getHeight()) * 0.5f);
            canvas.translate((float) (this.f2397b * scale), (float) (this.f2398c * scale));
            canvas.rotate((float) this.f2399d);
            mo3505a(0.0d, 0.0d, 1.0d, 0.0d, canvas);
            if (this.f2402g == 1) {
                mo3505a(0.0d, (this.f2401f * scale) + 0.0d, 1.0d, 0.0d, canvas);
                mo3505a(0.0d, 0.0d - (this.f2401f * scale), 1.0d, 0.0d, canvas);
            }
            mo3505a(0.0d, 0.0d, 0.0d, 1.0d, canvas);
            if (this.f2402g == 2) {
                mo3506a(this.f2400e * scale, this.f2401f * scale, canvas);
            }
            canvas.restore();
            mo3507b();
            double handleRadius = getHandleRadius();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.f2403h.length; i++) {
                canvas.drawCircle((float) this.f2403h[i].f2409a, (float) this.f2403h[i].f2410b, (float) (this.f2403h[i].f2411c >= 0 ? 1.25d * handleRadius : handleRadius), this.f2404i);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        boolean z;
        C0905a[] aVarArr;
        C0905a[] aVarArr2;
        if (this.f2402g == 0) {
            for (C0905a aVar : this.f2403h) {
                aVar.f2411c = -1;
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
        boolean z2 = false;
        int actionMasked = motionEvent.getActionMasked();
        if (actionMasked == 0 || actionMasked == 5) {
            z2 = true;
            double d = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            C0905a aVar2 = null;
            int actionIndex = motionEvent.getActionIndex();
            int pointerId = motionEvent.getPointerId(actionIndex);
            double x = (double) motionEvent.getX(actionIndex);
            double y = (double) motionEvent.getY(actionIndex);
            double handleRadius = getHandleRadius() * 2.5d;
            double d2 = handleRadius * handleRadius;
            C0905a[] aVarArr3 = this.f2403h;
            int length = aVarArr3.length;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < length) {
                C0905a aVar3 = aVarArr3[i];
                double d3 = aVar3.f2409a - x;
                double d4 = aVar3.f2410b - y;
                double d5 = (d3 * d3) + (d4 * d4);
                if (d5 >= d2 || d5 >= d) {
                    aVar3 = aVar2;
                    d5 = d;
                }
                i++;
                d = d5;
                aVar2 = aVar3;
            }
            if (aVar2 != null) {
                aVar2.f2411c = pointerId;
                aVar2.f2412d = x - aVar2.f2409a;
                aVar2.f2413e = y - aVar2.f2410b;
            }
        }
        if (actionMasked == 5) {
            for (C0905a aVar4 : this.f2403h) {
                aVar4.f2411c = -1;
            }
        }
        if ((actionMasked == 2 || actionMasked == 5) && motionEvent.getPointerCount() == 2) {
            double x2 = (double) (motionEvent.getX(0) - motionEvent.getX(1));
            double y2 = (double) (motionEvent.getY(0) - motionEvent.getY(1));
            double sqrt = Math.sqrt((x2 * x2) + (y2 * y2));
            double degrees = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2((double) (motionEvent.getY(0) - motionEvent.getY(1)), (double) (motionEvent.getX(0) - motionEvent.getX(1))));
            if (actionMasked == 2) {
                double d6 = sqrt / this.f2405j;
                this.f2400e *= d6;
                this.f2401f = d6 * this.f2401f;
                this.f2399d += degrees - this.f2408m;
            }
            this.f2405j = sqrt;
            this.f2408m = degrees;
        }
        if (actionMasked == 2 || actionMasked == 5 || actionMasked == 0 || actionMasked == 1 || actionMasked == 6) {
            double d7 = 0.0d;
            double d8 = 0.0d;
            int i2 = 0;
            for (int i3 = 0; i3 < motionEvent.getPointerCount(); i3++) {
                if (actionMasked != 6 || i3 != motionEvent.getActionIndex()) {
                    d7 += (double) motionEvent.getX(i3);
                    d8 += (double) motionEvent.getY(i3);
                    i2++;
                }
            }
            if (i2 > 0) {
                double d9 = d7 / ((double) i2);
                double d10 = d8 / ((double) i2);
                if (actionMasked == 2) {
                    boolean z3 = true;
                    for (C0905a aVar5 : this.f2403h) {
                        if (aVar5.f2411c >= 0) {
                            z3 = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (z3) {
                        double scale = 1.0d / getScale();
                        this.f2397b += (d9 - this.f2406k) * scale;
                        this.f2398c = (scale * (d10 - this.f2407l)) + this.f2398c;
                    }
                }
                this.f2406k = d9;
                this.f2407l = d10;
            }
        }
        if (actionMasked == 2) {
            z = true;
            int pointerCount = motionEvent.getPointerCount();
            for (int i4 = 0; i4 < pointerCount; i4++) {
                int pointerId2 = motionEvent.getPointerId(i4);
                double x3 = (double) motionEvent.getX(i4);
                double y3 = (double) motionEvent.getY(i4);
                for (C0905a aVar6 : this.f2403h) {
                    if (aVar6.f2411c == pointerId2) {
                        aVar6.f2409a = x3 - aVar6.f2412d;
                        aVar6.f2410b = y3 - aVar6.f2413e;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            z = z2;
        }
        if (actionMasked == 1 || actionMasked == 6) {
            z = true;
            int pointerId3 = motionEvent.getPointerId(motionEvent.getActionIndex());
            for (C0905a aVar7 : this.f2403h) {
                if (aVar7.f2411c == pointerId3) {
                    aVar7.f2411c = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (actionMasked == 3) {
            z = true;
            for (C0905a aVar8 : this.f2403h) {
                aVar8.f2411c = -1;
            }
        }
        if (z) {
            mo3508c();
            invalidate();
            if (this.f2396a != null) {
                this.f2396a.cameraView.requestRender();
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent) || z;
    }
}
```

Here's my cameraview class:

```
public class CameraView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {
    public static long maxsize = 1280;
    final String TAG = "CameraView";
    public Bitmap bitmap = null;
    public Bitmap bitmap0 = null;
    int bitmaptexture = -1;
    boolean bresize = true;

    public float f0c;
    public static Camera camera;
    SurfaceTexture cameraSurface;
    int cameraTexture;
    boolean created = false;
    boolean doloadbitmap = false;
    public boolean isFrontFacing;
    Framebuffer fa;
    Framebuffer fb;
    /* renamed from: h */
    int f1h;
    public static int ak;
    OnPhotoListener photoListener;
    Quad quad = new Quad();

    public float f2r;

    public float f3s;
    Shader shblur;
    Shader shconv;
    Shader shcopy;
    Shader shfina;
    Shader shflip;

    int f4w;

    public float f5y;

    public interface OnPhotoListener {
        void onPhoto(Bitmap bitmap);
    }

    public void takePhoto(OnPhotoListener l) {
        this.photoListener = l;
        requestRender();
    }

    static Bitmap takeScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        int[] b = new int[((y + h) * w)];
        int[] bt = new int[(w * h)];
        IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.wrap(b);
        ib.position(0);
        GLES20.glReadPixels(x, 0, w, y + h, 6408, 5121, ib);
        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while (i < h) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                int pix = b[(i * w) + j];
                bt[(((h - k) - 1) * w) + j] = ((-16711936 & pix) | ((pix << 16) & 16711680)) | ((pix >> 16) & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK);
            }
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setRenderer(this);
        setRenderMode(0);
        requestRender();
    }




    void m7x(Framebuffer src, Framebuffer dst, float dx, float dy) {
        dst.bind(this.f4w, this.f1h);
        this.shblur.use();
        this.shblur.tex("s", src.tex());
        this.shblur.set("o", (double) dx, (double) dy);
        this.shblur.set("y", (double) this.f5y);
        this.shblur.set("z", (double) this.f3s);
        this.quad.draw();
    }


    void m6x() {
        float radius = this.f2r;
        float rx = ((radius / 8.0f) / ((float) this.f4w)) * ((float) this.f1h);
        float ry = radius / 8.0f;
        m7x(this.fa, this.fb, rx / 8.0f, 0.0f);
        m7x(this.fb, this.fa, rx / 1.0f, 0.0f);
        m7x(this.fa, this.fb, 0.0f, ry / 8.0f);
        m7x(this.fb, this.fa, 0.0f, ry / 1.0f);
        m7x(this.fa, this.fb, rx / 8.0f, 0.0f);
        m7x(this.fb, this.fa, rx / 1.0f, 0.0f);
        m7x(this.fa, this.fb, 0.0f, ry / 8.0f);
        m7x(this.fb, this.fa, 0.0f, ry / 1.0f);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 _gl) {

        GLES20.glClear(16384);
        GLES20.glDisable(2929);
        GLES20.glDisable(2884);
        GLES20.glDisable(3042);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        Bitmap b = this.bitmap;

        if (b != null) {
            this.f4w = b.getWidth();
            this.f1h = b.getHeight();

            if (this.doloadbitmap) {
                loadbitmap();
                this.doloadbitmap = false;
            }
            this.fa.bind(this.f4w, this.f1h);
            this.shflip.use();
            this.shflip.tex("s", this.bitmaptexture);
            this.quad.draw();

        } else if (this.camera != null && this.cameraSurface != null) {
            Size cameraSize = null;

            try {
                this.camera.setPreviewTexture(this.cameraSurface);
                this.cameraSurface.updateTexImage();
                cameraSize = this.camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (this.camera != null && cameraSize != null && this.cameraSurface != null) {
                this.f4w = cameraSize.width;
                this.f1h = cameraSize.height;
                this.fa.bind(this.f4w, this.f1h);
                this.shconv.use();
                this.shconv.tex("s", this.cameraTexture, 0, 36197);
                this.quad.draw();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

        m6x();
        this.fb.bind(this.fa.f7w, this.fa.f6h);
        this.shfina.use();
        this.shfina.tex("s", this.fa.tex());
        this.shfina.set("c", (double) this.f0c);
        this.quad.draw();

        OnPhotoListener l = this.photoListener;
        this.photoListener = null;

        if (l != null) {
            Bitmap bmp = takeScreenshot(0, 0, this.f4w, this.f1h);
            l.onPhoto(bmp);
            bmp.recycle();
            requestRender();
        }
        Framebuffer.reset(getWidth(), getHeight());
        GLES20.glClear(16384);
        if ((((double) this.f4w) * 1.0d) / ((double) this.f1h) > (((double) getWidth()) * 1.0d) / ((double) getHeight())) {
            int h2 = (getWidth() * this.f1h) / this.f4w;
            GLES20.glViewport(0, (getHeight() - h2) / 2, getWidth(), h2);
        } else {
            int w2 = (getHeight() * this.f4w) / this.f1h;
            GLES20.glViewport((getWidth() - w2) / 2, 0, w2, getHeight());
        }
        this.shcopy.use();
        this.shcopy.tex("s", this.fb.tex());
        this.quad.draw();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 _gl, int width, int height) {
    }

    int genTexture() {
        int[] tt = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, tt, 0);
        return tt[0];
    }


    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 _gl, EGLConfig config) {
        this.fa = new Framebuffer();
        this.fb = new Framebuffer();

        this.shconv = new Shader(getContext(), R.raw.flip, R.raw.conv);
        this.shflip = new Shader(getContext(), R.raw.flip, R.raw.copy);
        this.shblur = new Shader(getContext(), R.raw.btex, R.raw.blur);
        this.shfina = new Shader(getContext(), R.raw.quad, R.raw.fina);
        this.shcopy = new Shader(getContext(), R.raw.quad, R.raw.copy);
        this.cameraTexture = genTexture();
        this.cameraSurface = new SurfaceTexture(this.cameraTexture);
        this.bitmaptexture = genTexture();
        this.created = true;
        this.doloadbitmap = true;
    }
    public void createCamera(int mReqCameraId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "createCamera");
        requestRender();
        if (this.camera == null) {
            try {
                if (mReqCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                    isFrontFacing = false;
                } else {
                   isFrontFacing = true;
                }
                this.camera = Camera.open(mReqCameraId);

               /*if(Share.back_camera){
                   this.camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
               }else{
                   this.camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
               }*/

                Parameters params = this.camera.getParameters();
                params.setRecordingHint(true);
                if (params.getSupportedFocusModes().contains("continuous-picture")) {
                    params.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");
                }
                Size best = null;
                for (Size s : params.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
                    if (best == null || s.width * s.height < best.width * best.height) {
                        best = s;
                    }
                }
                if (best != null) {
                    Log.i("Size", best.width + " " + best.height);
                    params.setPreviewSize(best.width, best.height);
                }
                this.camera.setParameters(params);
                this.camera.startPreview();
                setRenderMode(1);
            } catch (final Throwable ex) {
                ((Activity) getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


                    class C01341 implements OnClickListener {
                        C01341() {
                        }

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            CameraView.this.createCamera(0);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }
                    }

                    /* renamed from: camera.tiltshift.CameraView$1$2 */
                    class C01352 implements OnClickListener {
                        C01352() {
                        }

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }
                    }

                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    void destroyCamera() {
        Log.i("CameraView", "destroyCamera");
        if (this.camera != null) {
            this.camera.stopPreview();
            this.camera.release();

        }
        this.camera = null;
        setRenderMode(0);
        requestRender();
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap b) {
        this.bitmap0 = b;
        if (b != null && this.bresize && (((long) b.getWidth()) > maxsize || ((long) b.getHeight()) > maxsize)) {
            long mx = (long) Math.max(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
            b = createScaledBitmap2(b, (int) ((((long) b.getWidth()) * maxsize) / mx), (int) ((((long) b.getHeight()) * maxsize) / mx), true);
        }
        this.bitmap = b;
        this.doloadbitmap = true;
        requestRender();
    }

    static Bitmap createScaledBitmap2(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter) {
        Log.i("createScaledBitmap2", dstWidth + " " + dstHeight);
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setScale(((float) dstWidth) / ((float) src.getWidth()), ((float) dstHeight) / ((float) src.getHeight()));
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, m, paint);
        return result;
    }

    void loadbitmap() {
        Bitmap b = this.bitmap;
        if (b != null && this.created) {
            GLES20.glBindTexture(3553, this.bitmaptexture);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(3553, 10241, 9728);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(3553, 10240, 9728);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(3553, 10242, 33071);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(3553, 10243, 33071);
            GLUtils.texImage2D(3553, 0, b, 0);
            this.doloadbitmap = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like the code of your `OverlayView2` class is taken from reverse engineering

Comment: Yes exactly it's all reverse engineering @NileshRathod event the cameraview class

Comment: I guess that would require intervention from an expert of openGl